# Which response from server is the one that needs to have security headers

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, security, single-page-application

In this scenario I have a single page application
lets say: mysamplesite dot something.
This returns an html to the browser. In the html there are javascript files that are then downloaded by the browser and then the js files code is executed and additional AJAX calls are triggered from the code.

What response from the server needs to have the security headers? (Content-Security-Policy, X-Frame-Options, X-XSS-Protection, etc).

- The index.html response?
- The javascript files response?
- The AJAX response to the calls (XMLHttpRequest) made from the code
  execution?
- All of them (why)?

My guess is that only the index.html response needs to have these headers. But I am not sure about this.

I found this other question, but I dont think it answers my specific question
[Which server needs to return Access-Control-Allow-Origin header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018696/which-server-needs-to-return-access-control-allow-origin-header)

Comment: @lux Thanks for your answer but I am not sure if I understand. Lets say that I want to apply X-Frame-Options: deny. I would think that as long as the index.html has the header that should do the trick. Do all my static content (css and js) and AJAX that is loaded from that iframe needs to have the X-Frame-Options as well?

Comment: @lux In an additional scenario, lets say that my index.html does not have the "X-Frame-Options: deny" header, but the content that is loaded afterwards has it. Does that mean that the iframe is going to work initially (since the index allows it) but it will not load anything else since css, js files and AJAX responses will have the header "X-Frame-Options: deny"?

Comment: Doesn't CORS refers to the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header. In my comment I was asking about the "X-Frame-Options". I understand the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header need to be in the response of the requested file, but surely the "X-Frame-Options" needs to be only in the index.html isn't it? I didnt find clear information about that in the link.

Comment: Any endpoint that returns HTML could potentially benefit from the frame restrictions. It depends what you want to allow / disallow people to do with the specific data generated by those endpoints. There's no one-size-fits-all rule. You can read about what the rules do, you can read about some of the exploits that are known to exist around these rules, and then you can decide whether you need to mitigate that in each particular situation, or whether you need to allow some flexibility around how the data is used. If you can frame a more specific concern we can give a more specific answer.